# Date range validation

Tags: datetime, logging, interval, actionscript-3, flex

The following code is ran when the user presses a button to generate a log file based on the date selected. The `DatePicker` has a restrictive selected date range of the last 2 weeks including that same day. If the user leaves the page open for more than one day (very common), they will however be able to generate a log for a day that is too old. I've added this check to ensure that this isn't the case. I'm looking for a review on any part of this code.

```
[Bindable] private var mGeneratedLog:String;
[Bindable] private var mSelectedDate:Date;
[Bindable] private var mSelectableRange:Object;

private function getUploadMessages():void
{
    //validate range
    var now:Date = new Date();
    var tomorrow:Date = new Date(now.fullYear, now.month, now.date + 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var twoWeeksAgo:Date = new Date(now.fullYear, now.month, now.date - 14, 0, 0, 0, 0); 

    //refresh selectable range incase the page has been open too long.
    mSelectableRange = {rangeStart: twoWeeksAgo, rangeEnd: now};

    if (twoWeeksAgo.getTime() >= mSelectedDate.getTime())
    {
        mGeneratedLog = "Selected date is older than 2 weeks of age (Data has been purged).\nLog Not Generated."; 
    }
    else if( mSelectedDate.getTime() >= tomorrow.getTime())
    {
        mGeneratedLog = "Selected date has not happened yet (log would be empty).\nLog Not Generated."; 
    }
    else
    {
        mGeneratedLog = "Generating...";

        var formatter:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
        formatter.formatString = "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS.QQQ";

        var lParameters:Object = {date:formatter.format(mSelectedDate)}
        mDatalayer.callStatement("GenerateLog", lParameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I would store the result of `mSelectedData.getTime()` into a variable. It will save one method call and remove duplicate code.
2. The line that resets the data range seems a tad out of place; however, I am not sure about the rest of your implementation, so this might be the best place for it.
3. Also, I would check your first if-statement:

   ```
   if (twoWeeksAgo.getTime() >= mSelectedDate.getTime())
   ```

   Currently it will evaluate true (which is not expected) if the `Dates` are the same. From your description, it sounds like you want the date range to be **inclusive** not exclusive. Change the `>=` to simply `>` to get the result you expect:

   ```
   if (twoWeeksAgo.getTime() > mSelectedDate.getTime())
   ```

Other than that, the code looks fine; though I personally would capitalize the first word of each comment and put a space between it and the double slashes. So, `// Some comment` instead of `//some comment`. Just a personal preference.